# An Empirical observation on $6k\pm1$ form of prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Long story short, it has been more or less believed that there exists some structure underlying the inherent randomness of prime numbers. Numerous pioneering works of Carl Pomerance, Srinivasa Ramanjujan, Lehmer, James Maynard, and others have appended number theory with tools capable to explain the underlying structure.
Here, I'm posting a post with several empirical observations which I'm not able to prove and any help from the stack community will be of worth to me.

Let $p_n, p_{n+1}, p_{n+2}$ be consecutive prime numbers where $p_n$ is strictly greater than 3.

**Statement 1:** If $p_{n+1} - p_{n} = 2^k$, implies that, $p_{n+1} = 6K - (-1)^k$.

**Statement 2:** If $p_{n+2} - p_{n+1} = 6$, and $p_{n+1} - p_{n} = 2^k$ implies that, $p_{n+2} = 6K - (-1)^k$.

A few examples below illustrates above statements.

**Example 1** Let $p_{n+1} = 97$, and $p_n = 89$. $p_{n+1} - p_n = 2^3$. Then $p_{n+1} = 6K - (-1)^3$.

**Example 2** Let $p_{n+1} = 71$, and $p_n = 67$. $p_{n+1} - p_n = 2^2$. Then $p_{n+1} = 6K - (-1)^2$.

**Example 3** Let $p_{n+1} = 61$, and $p_n = 59$. $p_{n+1} - p_n = 2^1$. Then $p_{n+1} = 6K - (-1)^1$.

**Example 4** Let $p_{n+2} = 67$, $p_{n+1} = 61,$ and $p_n = 59$. $p_{n+1} - p_n = 2^1$. Then $p_{n+2} = 6K - (-1)^1$.

Above examples by no means proves the statement 1 and statement 2. I'll be thankful to the stack community to provide their valuable insights and help proving the following empirical observations.

Comment: Statement has $6k-(-1)^k$ but examples have $6K-(-1)^k$, which one is it? If the two $k$'s are the same then it would be clearly false.

Comment: As @Sil said, it has to be $6K-(-1)^k$. And in this case, it is clear that Statement 2 follows from Statement 1.

Comment: As for the first statement, show that if $2^k \equiv 2\pmod 6$, then $p_{n+1}\equiv 1\pmod 6$, $p_{n}\equiv -1\pmod 6$ (odd primes are always congruent $\pm 1\pmod 6$, so you have only few options). Similarly if $2^k \equiv 4 \pmod 6$. (also this happens for any two odd primes, not just consecutive)

Comment: $p_n = 2$ and $p_{n+1} = 3$ is a counterexample, so assume $k \geq 1$.

Comment: @Zag he did say all primes were strictly greater than $3$.

Comment: @Zag As mentioned $p_n$ is prime strictly greater than 3.

Comment: @Sil It was a small typing error from my side. Corrected it. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sil said in the comments, Statement 1 should be

*If $p_{n+1}-p_n=2^k$, $p_n>3$, then $p_{n+1}=6K-(-1)^k$ for some $K\in\mathbb{N}$.*

In this formulation, it is clear that Statement 2 follows from Statement 1.

EDIT: To see this, take $p_{n+2},p_{n+1}$, and $p_n$ such that $p_{n+2}-p_{n+1}=6$ and $p_{n+1}-p_n=2^k$. Then by Statement 1, $p_{n+1}=6K-(-1)^k$, and by manipulating the first equation, $p_{n+2}=6+p_{n+1} = 6+(6K-(-1)^k) = 6(K+1)-(-1)^k$, so Statement 2 is proven.

Now, let me prove this edited Statement 1. It is a standard congruence argument.

We know that every odd prime greater than $3$ has the form $p=6k\pm 1$. Thus, let $p_{n+1}=6k_1+\delta$, $p_n=6k_2+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon,\delta=\pm 1$ a priori independent of each other. Now, our assumption implies

$$2^k = p_{n+1}-p_n = 6\cdot(k_1-k_2)+(\delta-\epsilon).$$
As $p_{n+1}>p_n+1$, we see $k\geq 1$, and so we may write
$$2^{k-1} =  3\cdot(k_1-k_2)+\frac{\delta-\epsilon}{2}.$$
Since the RHS is an integer, this implies that $\delta=-\epsilon$, and so by direct manipulation,
$$k_1-k_2 = \frac{2^{k-1}-\delta}{3}.$$
Now, since RHS is again an integer, we must have that $2^{k-1}-\delta$ is divisible by $3$. And as $2^{k-1}-\delta = (-1)^{k-1}-\delta$ mod $3$, we see that this is true if and only if $\delta=(-1)^{k-1} = -(-1)^k$.

---

PS: Note that nowhere in my proof do I use that $p_{n+1}$ and $p_n$ are prime, except to get them on the form $6d\pm 1$. So the proof really shows that in the class of numbers with remainder $\pm 1$ mod $6$, if the difference of two such numbers is a power $k$ of $2$, and $k\geq 1$, then the larger number has remainder $(-1)^{k-1}$, and the smaller has remainder $(-1)^k$.

Thus, a prime greater than $3$ has remainder $(-1)^{k-1}$ mod $6$ if its difference with any smaller number from the above class is $2^k$.

Conversely, if we know the remainder is 1, then the only possible powers of $2$ arising as a difference with the above class are odd powers (respectively $-1$ and even powers).

Comment: If possible, can you please elaborate, how second statement is equivalent to first? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: And also, I would like to know if there is any practical use of such an observation. I'll be thankful if you can elaborate your answer with a few practical situations where this fact demonstrates its role, like in theorems relevant to prime numbers.

Comment: I have edited my comment to show how the statements are related. Concerning applications, I am not sure what you are looking for. You are already saying something concrete about prime gaps and congruence relations, which is kinda neat. I doubt your Statement 1 implies any deep results about primes, though.

Comment: I was not getting about equivalence of statement 2 with statement 1, however, I got it now. Thank you sir.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating the answer sir.